# How to store hexadecimal identifier in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I use SQL Server 2017. I am extracting data from external system where IDs are in hexadecimal format I belive, samples below:

```
5af1a437e696991080f284c2
5af1a95be696991080f287ca
5af1adafe696991080f28af8
5af1b130e696991080f28dc4
5af1b130e696991080f28dc5
5af1b130e696991080f28dc6
```

I would like to effectively store those IDs and use them in joins.
I have them as varchar's at the moment so they won't be great to index or use in joins.
Ideally I would like to convert them to INTs. 
How can I do it and is this correct approach?
Should I rather use different data type e.g. varbinary and what lenght varbinary (8), varbinary(16)?
I understand that best would be to create surrogate key in the format I want and us that in data model but this is for internal use and I want to keep this simple.

Comment: Those are 12 byte values, and they'll fit neither an `INT` nor a `BIGINT`. You can split them up, but that's not likely to give you much gain over just storing them as `BINARY(12)` and indexing that. Aside from using `BINARY(12)` in parameters, on the T-SQL end you can also convert from and to hexstring format using `CONVERT` with the `style` option (e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(12), '5af1a95be696991080f287ca', 2)`) or use constants directly by prefixing them with `0x` (e.g. `SELECT 0x5af1a95be696991080f287ca`). (This is assuming they'll always be 12 bytes long, which is an assumption.)

Comment: Unless you've identified a significant performance issue with using varchar(n), if you want to 'keep this simple', just use the varchar key. It'll work in joins and indexes just fine... unless you really need 'numeric' order for some reason.

Comment: `000000005af1b130e696991080f28dc4` - valid GUID

Comment: @IvanStarostin: that value fits in a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, but there's no guarantee of "global uniqueness", so that would be misleading at best -- and colliding at worst.

Comment: @JeroenMostert these values look strange and suspiciously remind (sequential) guids which are often used for PK, so I wanted to point OP to look carefully at source data and the way he parses or loads them.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: if they *are* GUIDs, special care must be taken, because the bytes are not in [the order SQL Server uses to store GUIDs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121869/sql-server-uniqueidentifier-guid-internal-representation). Converting `0x000000005af1b130e696991080f28dc4` to a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is definitely not going to be right and some complicated unswizzling would be needed. (I strongly suspect that they are not actually GUIDs no matter how you slice them, but I'm too lazy to pick them apart and check the version/type bits right now.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert ...I did not suggest to append zeros to every value. I'm pointing out a possible misunderstanding of the nature or format of the imported data. And I tried to imagine how hard would it be to "external developers" to support such a unique format which for sure is not a hash of anything and how would they increment those values and so on. The simplest solution for data _like that_ is GUID so my assumption is: broken data during import. Due to badly defined separator for flat-file or something like that. Or total misunderstanding of external data format.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: alright, I'm glad we cleared that up. I couldn't infer that just from your "valid GUID" comment. :-)

Comment: I appreciate insightful discussion. Data comes from CSV. there is no zeros in front. All values are 24 characters long. All entities in source system are using IDs in that format. I will go ahead and use BINARY(12). Thank you. If you would like me to accept your answer please post it as answer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it seems data gets truncated when I use suggested binary(12) please see updated question

Comment: You can't use `CAST` -- that will convert characters to their code points. You have to use `CONVERT(BINARY(12), SourceID, 2)` to convert it as a hexstring.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert I see mistake. I removed update from main question to avoid confusion.